# Azure Spark how to configure application retry limit

Tags: azure, azure-hdinsight

I am currently running Azure HD insight Spark cluster and by default if an application fails, it retries 5 times. I would like to change this and set it to 2. Do you know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass this in as a configuration point to spark-submit.
`spark-submit ... --conf spark.yarn.maxAppAttempts=2`

You can also set an override at the cluster level in Ambari. You can access `Custom spark-defaults` via `spark->configs` and set overrides via the ambari UI.

Comment: I was looking at doing it using the Ambari UI however I cannot find an appropriate configuration options under Advanced Saprk2 Default in Ambari UI. The options I am seeing are .... spark.eventLog.enabled  spark.executor.. spark.history... spark.yarn.history... spark.yarn.queue... spark.driver and a few more but nothing suggests retry configuration

Comment: You can add a new property in custom spark-defaults. I have edited my answer to reflect this @jane

Comment: It has worked. Thanks. I also had to restart the services.